# Teradata REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE Inserting Spaces between Numbers

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I am having trouble with Teradata's REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE.  It is separating the results correctly, but it is inserting spaces between each individual number.  I used CHAR2HEXINT and found the Hex of the space is 00.  Here is the statement I am using:

```
SELECT *  
FROM TABLE(
       REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE('2625 1410', '2625 1410', '[ \t\r\n\v\f]' , 'i') 
         RETURNS (outkey VARCHAR(250), token_ndx INTEGER, token VARCHAR(220) )
   ) AS t1;
```

It returns 2 6 2 5 as a row and 1 4 1 0 as a row.  I want the results to be 2625 as a row and 1410 as a row.  Is there something I am doing wrong that is adding the spaces?  Is there a way to get rid of the spaces?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this,replace only REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE('2625 1410', '2625 1410', '[ \t]' , 'i')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE returns UNICODE strings :-) 
But as you didn't specify the character set for the RETURN columns the parser assumes LATIN and this results in binary zeroes.

Simply add CHARACTER SET UNICODE:

```
SELECT *  
FROM TABLE(
       REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE('2625 1410', '2625 1410', '[ \t\r\n\v\f]' , 'i') 
         RETURNS (outkey VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET UNICODE
                 ,token_ndx INTEGER
                 ,token VARCHAR(220) CHARACTER SET UNICODE )
   ) AS t1;
```